# Outputing Data to CSV with use of expressions

Tags: powershell, csv

I'm attempting to gather data via WMI and then output that to a CSV once I've setup the tables using expressions, but I'm not getting the output I'd expect.

```
$Ips = "192.168.1.1", "192.168.1.2"
foreach ($ip in $Ips) {
  $Profiles = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -Computer $ip -ea 0
  Write-Host `n$ip
  foreach ($profile in $Profiles) {
    @{Expression={$ip};Label="IPAddress"}, @{Expression={"\\"+$ip+"\"+$profile.LocalPath};Label="SharePath"} |
      Export-Csv -Path "$HOME\Desktop\Found.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The feature you're trying to use here is called [calculated properties](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff730948.aspx), and you need `Select-Object` to use it:

```
Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_UserProfile -Computer $ip -EA 0 |
  Select-Object @{Expression={$ip};Label="IPAddress"},
    @{Expression={'\\{0}\{1}' -f $ip, $profile.LocalPath};Label="SharePath"} |
  Export-Csv -Path "$HOME\Desktop\Found.csv" -Append -NoTypeInformation
```